# Elastic: Error when try to initialize synonym token filter

Tags: elasticsearch

Synonym Token Filter gives an Error.

**Elasticsearch version**
Version: 6.2.2, Build: 10b1edd/2018-02-16T19:01:30.685723Z, JVM: 1.8.0_161

**Plugins installed**:
Opennlp

**JVM version**
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

**OS version**
Linux server 4.4.0-131-generic #157-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 12 15:51:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Description of the problem including expected versus actual behavior**:

When I try to reproduce the following: https://qbox.io/blog/synonym-token-filter-wordnet-applications

However, if I change the tokenizer to "standard", instead of "lowercase", everything is fine. Does anyone have an idea what to do?

I get the following error.

Error: 400 - failed to build synonyms
ES stack trace:

type: illegal_argument_exception
  reason: failed to build synonyms

**Steps to reproduce**:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test_index' -d '{
 "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "synonym": {
        "type": "synonym",
        "format": "wordnet",
        "synonyms_path": "analysis/wn_s.pl"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "wordnet-synonym-analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "lowercase",
        "filter": [
          "synonym"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Do you put synonyms in synonyms_path correctly?

Comment: The path is correct. If I use `tokenizer = "standard`, everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Use standard tokenizer and add lowercase as filter.

```
"analyzer": {
  "synonymAnalyzer": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "synonym"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Then you, that works. Here are more solutions https://discuss.elastic.co/t/synonym-token-filter-error/160016/2